# How to enable kafka consumer static membership in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

The [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#message-listener-container) of spring kafka says that we can configure static membership after setting concurrency to greater than 1. But, I found that `group.instance.id` is set to null when I checked the consumer configuration.

> Starting with versions 2.3.8, 2.4.6, the ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer now supports Static Membership when the concurrency is greater than one. The group.instance.id is suffixed with -n with n starting at 1. This, together with an increased session.timeout.ms, can be used to reduce rebalance events, for example, when application instances are restarted.

Does anyone have an idea how to configure kafka static membership in a Spring Cloud Stream application.

Spring Boot version: 2.6.2

Kafka Cluster version: 2.6.0

Spring Kafka version: 2.8.0

Properties summary:

```yaml
spring:
 cloud:
  stream:
   default:
    consumer:
     concurrency: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.properties.group.instance.id`

Spring will append `-n` for each consumer created by the concurrency setting.